# Curious circular inheritance with mix-ins in C++

Tags: c++, templates, circular-dependency, mixins, crtp

What is a good way to unscramble the circular inheritance here?

```c
class Node {
   // ...
public:
   list<Node*> neighbors() { /* ... */ }
   void update() { }
}

template<class NodeType>
class HasImportance : public virtual NodeType {
   double m_importance = 0.0;
public:
   void receive_importance(double imp) { /* ... */ }
   void give_importance() {
      for (auto neighbor : this->neighbors())
         neighbor->receive_importance(m_importance /* ... */);
   }
};

class TrafficLight : public HasImportance<TrafficLight>, virtual Node {
public:
   list<TrafficLight*> neighbors() { ... }
   void update() { give_importance(); /* ... */ }
};
```

It fails (gcc 4.7.0) because `TrafficLight` is an incomplete type
when `HasImportance` tries to inherit from it.

The real problem is that HasImportance needs to know the type returned by
`neighbors()`. If `HasImportance` inherits from
`Node`, then it thinks `neighbors()` returns a list of
`Node*`, not `TrafficLight*`, and consequently doesn't
know that it can call `receive_importance()` on the items. Similar
problem if `HasImportance` doesn't inherit at all.

BTW, what I'm trying to do is make a few mix-ins to help define a variety of
different kinds of graphs easily and to unit-test each mix-in separately. For
example, I should be able to define the node class for a graph of traffic lights by just writing
something like `class TrafficLight : public HasImportance, HasState<3>,
virtual Node { }`.

I've come up with three ways to solve this, but all seem ugly. (1)
`static_cast<NodeType*>`. (2) `TrafficLight` passes its
`this` to `HasImportance` in its constructor. This way,
`HasImportance` doesn't need to inherit at all; it just stores a
pointer to (ahem) itself, and the template parameter provides the type of the
pointer. (3) Make `Node` a class template, like this:

```c
template<class NodeType>
class Node {
public:
   list<NodeType*> neighbors() { /* ... */ }
}

class TrafficLight : public HasImportance<Node<TrafficLight>> { /* ... */ }
```

That compiles and it doesn't introduce a gratuitous copy of `this`,
but it seems…a little too curious.

Is there a code smell here? Should I approach these graphs in a completely
different way?

Comment: Using `static_cast<NodeType*>(this)` is *normal* in CRTP.

Comment: @KennyTM: I would even go so far and say that this is the key in using the CRTP

Comment: Thanks. I cringe at using static_cast, because it seems like I'm ignoring a sign (a "smell") that something deeper is wrong. If it's "normal" in CRTP, I guess I won't resist so much. This is my first CRTP. Can you tell? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(3) but a bit differently.

```
template <class NodeType>
class Node { ... };

template<class NodeType>
class HasImportance : public virtual Node<NodeType> { ... };

class TrafficLight : public HasImportance<TrafficLight> { ... };
```

Looks entirely straightforward to me, not more curious than the CRTP itself.

Comment: Thanks! I like this a lot better even though it's a small difference. The "compile-time interface" to the mix-ins is now simple and pretty immune to changes elsewhere in the code, unlike my version.